# What is the proper way to implement a large bit field in datanucleus?

Tags: java, postgresql, post, datanucleus

I  am developing a java application with datanucleus and postgresql. In my table named “Book”, i want to use a long bit field for status. This field can be  up to 3000 bit long. Now i don’t know how to implement this using datanucleus. I tried to use ‘BitSet’  in my java code and saw in postgresql part ‘bytea’ field is created. Now what should be standard way to implement this varying bit field. Also, what is the mapping i should use and is it possible to perform different type of query using boolean operations? Is there any resources from where i can learn these things.

Edit1:
Java class:

```
@PersistenceCapable(table = "BOOK",
detachable = "true")  
public class Book implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Persistent(column = "USER_UUID")
   private String userUuid;


   @PrimaryKey
   @Persistent(column = "Book_UUID") 
   private String bookUuid; 

   @Persistent
   private BitSet shareeInfo = new BitSet();
}
```

**Schema:**
   Table: Book
   Field: bookUuid, userUuid, shareeInfo, bookName and many other fields.

Each user will have at most 3000 friends (other user). Now, for each of the bit in shareeInfo field is for one of my friends. When i share a book with one of my friends, i will update a particular bit of shareeInfo field of that book so that sharing can be done with little memory and easily.

Comment: want to give us a clue which API you're using? Resources are the DataNucleus documentation, or the JDO spec, or the JPA spec ... dependent on what you are doing!

Comment: We are using JDO 4.0.3.

Comment: @NeilStockton, I have added class and schema in Edit1 section in Post.

Comment: and the problem is? You haven't specified any metadata defining the column type to use (jdbcType, sqlType) so it creates what it needs for that datastore

Comment: @NeilStockton  Would you please elaborate ? I am not realizing what you are saying as i have no idea about jbdc type or sqlType and how to use these types. Is there something for postgresql ?

Comment: So you haven't read any JDO documentation? http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jdo/orm/schema_mapping.html#columntypes

Comment: I have read documentation earlier. The problem is, it's hard for beginner like me to have good understanding by reading DN documentation. I have lots of confusions. My question was, how "long-varying-bit field" is implemented in DN+JDO+PostgreSql and how we can query using Bitwise AND, OR operations. By reading your link, i tried to override mapping and tried to use "LONGVARBINARY" but it is producing same bytea field in postgresql which is also produced if i don't override. Now i don't know, how to query that bytea field or what should be the  appropriate field in postgresql? @NeilStockton

Comment: LONGVARBINARY is a JDBC TYPE. "bytea" and "long bit varying" are SQL types. LONGVARBINARY maps to "bytea", hence specifying JDBC type as "LONGVARBINARY" won't make the blindest difference. I doubt very much if the PostgreSQL JDBC driver bothers listing "long bit varying" as a valid type (and DataNucleus relies on this info). You could enable support for that SQL type yourself by updating the DataNucleus PostgreSQLAdapter class.

Comment: Ok, I am trying what you told. Would you please tell me, when we need a large(2000-3000) bit field to store some kind of  status what are the appropriate data types in java and PostgreSql sides while we will query in table using lots of bit wise operations. @NeilStockton